# Difference between $\|A^n\|$ and $\|A\|^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

In matrix norms, what is the difference between $\|A^n\|$ and $\|A\|^n$?

Comment: Consider $A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $n=2$.

Answer (score 4):

For example, let $A=({}^0_0\,{}^2_0)$ and suppose we're talking the operator norm.

To compute $\|A^2\|$ we first take the square of $A$, giving $({}^0_0\,{}^0_0)$, and take the norm of that, which is $0$.

To compute $\|A\|^2$, we first take the norm of $A$, which is $2$, and square that, giving $4$.